# Discord.py how to make button that will run command that has multiple random responses

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a python discord bot. I have this one command that will end up giving a random reply, the code that I found works perfect for it, but I wanted to add a button that would appear with the reply that could be clicked to run the command again instead of having to continuously retype the command. Also, if possible I would like it to only be accessible by a specific role

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    items = [
    discord.Embed(title = "this is for a test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the second test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the third test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the fourth test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the fifth test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the sixth test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the seventh test"),
    discord.Embed(title = "this is the eighth test")]
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    await ctx.reply(embed=randomitem) # embed= - for send discord.Embed]
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button = discord.ui.Button(label="Click me")
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.send(view=view)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient way but this will do:

```
randomitem = None
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    global randomitem
    items = [
        discord.Embed(title="this is for a test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the second test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the third test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fourth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fifth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the sixth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the seventh test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the eighth test")
    ]
    
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    msg = await ctx.reply(embed=randomitem)
    
    async def change_embed(interaction):
        global randomitem
        next_embed = random.choice(items)
        while next_embed == randomitem:
            next_embed = random.choice(items)
        randomitem = next_embed
        await msg.edit(embed=next_embed)
        
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button = discord.ui.Button(label="Click me", custom_id="click_me")
    button.callback = change_embed
    view.add_item(button)
    
    await ctx.send(view=view)
```

How it works:

- randomitem as global variable (set to None by default)
- function `change_embed` for changing embed on button click
- `button.callback` checking for button click
- callback calls the function
- `while loop` checks if randomitem is the same as next item
- `msg.edit` edits the embed

*Note: click will return "interaction falied" error in discord, because you did not respond to the interaction*