# Discord.py how to make button on reply run the same command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and I have this command that gives a random reply with a button that basically runs the command again, but I can't figure out how to get the reply to have the same button to run the command again, basically like a loop, if that makes sense. If possible, would there be a way to add in so that only members with a specific role could use the command?

```
randomitem = None
@bot.command()
async def butt(ctx):
    global randomitem
    items = [
        discord.Embed(title="this is for a test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the second test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the third test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fourth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fifth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the sixth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the seventh test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the eighth test")
    ]
    
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    msg = await ctx.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=randomitem)
    
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        global randomitem
        try:
            await interaction.response.defer()
        except:
            pass
        next_embed = random.choice(items)
        while next_embed == randomitem:
            next_embed = random.choice(items)
        randomitem = next_embed
        await msg.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=next_embed)
        
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button = discord.ui.Button(label="!valshot", custom_id="!valshot")
    button.callback = button_callback
    view.add_item(button)

    await ctx.send(view=view)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically did the same as with your last post:

```
view = None
randomitem = None
@bot.command()
async def butt(ctx):
    global randomitem
    items = [
        discord.Embed(title="this is for a test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the second test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the third test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fourth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the fifth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the sixth test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the seventh test"),
        discord.Embed(title="this is the eighth test")
    ]
    
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    global view
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button = discord.ui.Button(label="!valshot", custom_id="!valshot")
    view.add_item(button)
    msg = await ctx.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=randomitem,view=view)
    
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        global randomitem
        global view
        try:
            await interaction.response.defer()
        except:
            pass
        next_embed = random.choice(items)
        while next_embed == randomitem:
            next_embed = random.choice(items)
        randomitem = next_embed
        await msg.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=next_embed,view=view)
    button.callback = button_callback
```

How it works:

- global view variable
- pass in view to the reply
- create view before using it

Comment: for anybody wondering OP = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716871/discord-py-how-to-make-button-that-will-run-command-that-has-multiple-random-res/77717327#77717327