# discord.py How to send specific image for each embed random generator

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

With this code I got I'm able to have my command send random messages with the command, the problem I'm facing now is trying to set a different image for each one that sends with the message and just trying to send an embed image.
I've tried a few ways, but have just been getting different errors.

```
view = None   
randomitem = None
@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx):
    global randomitem
    items = [
        discord.Embed(title="test1"),
        discord.Embed(title="test2"),
        discord.Embed(title="test3"),
        discord.Embed(title="test4"),
    ]
    
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    global view
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button = discord.ui.Button(label="!test", custom_id="!test", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    view.add_item(button)
    msg = await ctx.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=randomitem,view=view)
    
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        global randomitem
        try:
            await interaction.response.defer()
        except:
            pass
        next_embed = random.choice(items)
        while next_embed == randomitem:
            next_embed = random.choice(items)
        randomitem = next_embed
        await msg.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=next_embed,view=view)
    button.callback = button_callback
```

Comment: OP for anyone wondering = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716871/discord-py-how-to-make-button-that-will-run-command-that-has-multiple-random-res/77717327#77717327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like you're so close...

I would recommend building all of the embeds first, then creating a list of the embeds.

```
embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Test1", description="This is Test1")
embed1.add_image(url="https://url.to.image")

embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Test2", description="This is Test2")
embed2.add_image(url="https://url.to.image")

embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Test3", description="This is Test3")
embed3.add_image(url="https://url.to.image")

embed_lst = [embed1, embed2, embed3]
await ctx.send(embed=random.choice(embed_lst)
```

By having complete and full embeds already made, you can call a random embed from a list, as if to draw a new card.

Comment: there were a few things I had to change, but this helped a lot! Am I supposed to edit the post with what I did?

Comment: @Anonymouspls No need to post what you did, but if you DID want to, I would recommend editing the Original Post, as to not distract from people submitting answers. Thank you for choosing my answer, and I'm glad it was able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me!

```
view = None   
randomitem = None
@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx):
global randomitem

embed1 = discord.Embed(title="test1", description="this is test1")
embed1.set_image(url="")
    
embed2 = discord.Embed(title="test2", description="This is test2")
embed2.set_image(url="")
    
embed3 = discord.Embed(title="test3", description="this is test3")
embed3.set_image(url="")


embed_lst = [embed1, embed2, embed3]
randomitem = random.choice(embed_lst)
global view
view = discord.ui.View()
button = discord.ui.Button(label="!test", custom_id="!test", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
view.add_item(button)
msg = await ctx.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=random.choice(embed_lst),view=view)

async def button_callback(interaction):
    global randomitem
    try:
        await interaction.response.defer()
    except:
        pass
    next_embed = random.choice(embed_lst)
    while next_embed == randomitem:
        next_embed = random.choice(embed_lst)
    randomitem = next_embed
    await msg.reply("Drawing a card...", embed=next_embed,view=view)
button.callback = button_callback
```